# Plotly express :How to label a bar-chart with multiple traces.?

Tags: express, plotly, label, bar-chart

This code gives me the desired chart. But how do i add the total labels for both cols ?

> fig = px.bar(d, x=d['AXIS'], y=['col1','col2'], barmode='group',text=)

I succeeded to do it for one trace.

> fig = px.bar(d, x=d['AXIS'], y='col1', barmode='group',text=d['col1'])

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
fig = px.bar(d, x=d['AXIS'], y=['col1','col2'],
barmode='group',text_auto=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.